# Flexbox Progress Bar Animation - Incorrect Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a progress bar with an animation. It works if I don't have inner text but as soon as I add the inner text the width calculations are different for some reason. I've tried working with the different `width()` functions and I've tried adding up each segment but every time the text throws off the width for some reason.

Here's what I have - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a54jgck/4/)

```js
/** Progress Bar Animation **/
function animate_progress_bar() {
  if (!$('.progressBar').length) {
    return false;
  }

  $('.progressBar').each(function() {
    var num_total = $(this).find('.seg').length;
    var num_fill = $(this).find('.fill').length;
    var percent = 100 - ((num_fill / num_total) * 100);
    var speed = 2000 / num_fill;

    $(this).find('.progradient').animate({
      'width': percent + '%'
    }, speed);
  });
}
animate_progress_bar();
```

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flex > * {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.progressBar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.progressBar .seg {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 2;
}
.progressBar .seg:last-of-type {
  border-right: 0;
}
.progressBar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(30, 87, 153);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=1);
}
.progressBar .progradient {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.progressBar.large {
  border-radius: 40px;
}
.progressBar.large .seg {
  min-height: 40px;
}
.progressBar.large .text {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width: 160px">
  <div class="progressBar small">
    <div class="seg fill"></div>
    <div class="seg fill"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="progradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progressBar large">
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="progradient"></div>
</div>

<div class="progressBar large">
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="progradient"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add `flex: 1;` to your segment class.

---

> flex: `<positive-number>`:
>
> Equivalent to flex: `<positive-number> 1 0`. Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.

*Source: [**W3C**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)*

---

Class changed:

```
.progressBar.large .seg {
    min-height: 40px;
    flex: 1; /* Added property*/
}
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
/** Progress Bar Animation **/
function animate_progress_bar() {
  if (!$('.progressBar').length) {
    return false;
  }

  $('.progressBar').each(function() {
    var num_total = $(this).find('.seg').length;
    var num_fill = $(this).find('.fill').length;
    var percent = 100 - ((num_fill / num_total) * 100);
    var speed = 2000 / num_fill;

    $(this).find('.progradient').animate({
      'width': percent + '%'
    }, speed);
  });
}
animate_progress_bar();
```

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flex > * {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.progressBar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.progressBar .seg {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 2;
}
.progressBar .seg:last-of-type {
  border-right: 0;
}
.progressBar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(30, 87, 153);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 27%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 74%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=1);
}
.progressBar .progradient {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.progressBar.large {
  border-radius: 40px;
}
.progressBar.large .seg {
  min-height: 40px;
  flex: 1;
}
.progressBar.large .text {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width: 160px">
  <div class="progressBar small">
    <div class="seg fill"></div>
    <div class="seg fill"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="seg"></div>
    <div class="progradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progressBar large">
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg fill"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="progradient"></div>
</div>

<div class="progressBar large">
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg fill flex">
    <div class="text">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="seg"></div>
  <div class="progradient"></div>
</div>
```